# Reorder XML nodes based on condition in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have an input XML that i have to restructure into another XML using XSLT.
The incoming XML looks like this

```
 <Header>
    <Rejection>
        <Code>Code1</Code>
        <Text>Text1</Text>
    </Rejection>
    <Rejection>
        <Code>Code2</Code>
        <Text>Text2</Text>
    </Rejection>
    <Rejection>
        <Code>Code3</Code>
        <Text>Text3</Text>
    </Rejection>
</Header>
```

Whenever the Rejection has a code value of Code3 then Code3/Text3 tag has to be the first tag. The position of Code3 could be anywhere in the incoming XML but it has to be the first rejection tag in the output. This is my current XSLT

```
<xsl:for-each select="/Header/Rejection">
    <xsl:if test ="Code='Code3'">
        <REJECTION>
            <REJECTCODE><xsl:value-of select="Code"></xsl:value-of></REJECTCODE>
            <REJECTREASON><xsl:value-of select="Text"></xsl:value-of></REJECTREASON>
        </REJECTION>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
<xsl:for-each select="/Header/Rejection">
    <xsl:if test ="not(Code='Code3')">
        <REJECTION>
            <REJECTCODE><xsl:value-of select="Code"></xsl:value-of></REJECTCODE>
            <REJECTREASON><xsl:value-of select="Text"></xsl:value-of></REJECTREASON>
        </REJECTION>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Now is there a way to prevent the 2 loops and get the result in single loop.
The output XML has to be like this:

```
<Header>
    <REJECTION>
        <REJECTCODE>Code3</REJECTCODE>
        <REJECTREASON>Text3</REJECTREASON>
    </REJECTION>
    <REJECTION>
        <REJECTCODE>Code1</REJECTCODE>
        <REJECTREASON>Text1</REJECTREASON>
    </REJECTION>
    <REJECTION>
        <REJECTCODE>Code2</REJECTCODE>
        <REJECTREASON>Text2</REJECTREASON>
    </REJECTION>
</Header>
```

**Note:** The codes are just a sample.It is actually alpha numeric and is not in sortable order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/Header">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Rejection">
            <xsl:sort select="number(Code='Code3')" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Rejection">
   <REJECTION>
        <REJECTCODE>
            <xsl:value-of select="Code"/>
        </REJECTCODE>
        <REJECTREASON>
            <xsl:value-of select="Text"/>
        </REJECTREASON>
    </REJECTION>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I am sorry i should have been clear.The codes i have mentioned are mocked up. It wont be in sorting order.It is alpha numeric code.I have changed the question to reflect that.

Comment: @NiranjanKC I don't see anything new that would require changing my answer. The code can be anything you want. I am not sorting by the code. I  am sorting by the code being equal to a given string.

Comment: Is there an alternative to this <xsl:template match="Rejection">. I am not able to use this condition as the XSLT already has a template defined at the root Header level(It has a bunch of other tags in between).Whatever i try is printing all the tag contents of Rejection in it?

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand what you're saying.

Comment: My XSLT has a <xsl:template match="/"> at the top and closes at the last line. I am not able to put this <xsl:template match="Rejection"> in between.

Comment: So put the sort in the `xsl:for-each` instruction.

Comment: Thanks that worked. I am not able to Mark your answer as i am new to the community.

Answer (score -1):

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Header">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Rejection[3]"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Rejection[1]"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Rejection[2]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
You may simply apply according to your need.
```

Comment: The question says clearly: "The position of Code3 could be anywhere in the incoming XML".